# Trying to read files named file1,file2,file3 using for loop in Python

Tags: python, csv

I am pretty new to python and trying to run a script to edit csv files. The problem I am facing is that I need to split the csv files into smaller pieces(as they are large files and getting memory errors) and then run another script to edit the files but when im trying to append these two scripts and run the test, the script is reading only the first small file and not reading the rest of the files.
For example: When I split the main csv file, the files are getting split and the names come as big-1.csv,big-2.csv. Then when the script is picking up the files to edit, only big-1.csv is getting edited and rest are not getting edited. 
The script is:

```
import csv
from csv import DictWriter

divisor = 990
outfileno = 1
outfile = None

with open('MOCK_DATA.csv', 'r', newline='') as infile:
    infile_iter = csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t')
    header = next(infile_iter)

    for index, row in enumerate(infile_iter):
        if index % divisor == 0:
            if outfile:
                outfile.close()

            outfilename = 'big-{}.csv'.format(outfileno)
            outfile = open(outfilename, 'w', newline='')
            outfileno += 1
            writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
            writer.writerow(header)

        writer.writerow(row)

    # Don't forget to close the last file
    if outfile:
        outfile.close()

#export the data
# with correct quoting, and that you are stuck with what you have.


for i in range(1,2):    

        with open("big-" + str(i) + ".csv") as people_file:
            next(people_file)
            corrected_people = []
            for person_line in people_file:
                chomped_person_line = person_line.rstrip()
                person_tokens = chomped_person_line.split(",")

                # check that each field has the expected type
                try:
                    corrected_person = {
                    "id": person_tokens[0],
                    "first_name":person_tokens[1],
                    "last_name": "".join(person_tokens[2:-3]),
                    "email":person_tokens[-3],
                    "gender":person_tokens[-2],
                    "ip_address":person_tokens[-1]  

                    }

                    if not corrected_person["ip_address"].startswith(
                            "") and corrected_person["ip_address"] !="n/a":
                        raise ValueError

                    corrected_people.append(corrected_person)
                except (IndexError, ValueError):
                    # print the ignored lines, so manual correction can be performed later.
                    print("Could not parse line: " + chomped_person_line)

            with open("fix-" + str(i) + ".csv", "w") as corrected_people_file:
                writer = DictWriter(
                    corrected_people_file,
                    fieldnames=[
                        "id","first_name","last_name","email","gender","ip_address"
                ],delimiter=',')
                writer.writeheader()
                writer.writerows(corrected_people)
```

I think this maybe an issue with reading the smaller files in the for loop. The script is running without any error. Please help.

Comment: `for i in range(1,2):` looks incorrect - It only gets you 1. Try a range from 1 to 6, which should get you 1 thru 5.

Comment: i have slipt the file into two parts thats why i in 1,2